Vectorised linear interpolation where x, xp and yp are all 2D
I have a similar issue to Linear interpolation of two 2D arrays.
But in my case x, xp and yp are all 2 dimensional. For instance:
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[2, 3], [1, 2]], dtype=float)
xp = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]], dtype=float)
yp = np.array([[0, 1, 3, 6, 7], [0, 3, 5, 7, 9]], dtype=float)

I can do it simply with a loop, but this is slow for big arrays.
result = np.array([np.interp(x[i], xp[i], yp[i]) for i in range(len(x))])

Is there a possibility to do it in a vectorised way?

Did you follow the see also link to scipy? interp1d works for multiple y values (same x for all).~

@hpaulj, sadly my x is different per row. I have edited the example.

So all the interpolations have in common are the dimensions?  Otherwise they are independent operations?

@hpaulj, correct.

As noted in the comment, scipy.interpolate.interp1d allows for y to be an n-d array.
# your code
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[2, 3], [2, 3]], dtype=float)
xp = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]], dtype=float)
yp = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 3, 5, 7, 9]], dtype=float)

ref = np.array([np.interp(x[i], xp[i], yp[i]) for i in range(len(x))])

# using SciPy
from scipy import interpolate
interpolator = interpolate.interp1d(xp[0], yp)
res = interpolator(x[0])

np.testing.assert_allclose(res, ref)

In your case, this is possible because you are interpolating from the same x coordinates for different sets of y coordinates. (If the x-coordinates to be interpolated needed to be different for different slices of y, you would still need to loop, unfortunately.)

Sadly, the x, xp and yp can be  different per row. At least now I know a loop is the only way, thanks.

Well, if linear is all you need, it's not too hard to write your own. I'll expand the answer.

It sounds like you need a more general version of interp that allows x, xp, and fp to be n-d arrays.
Suppose x and y are of shape (m, n), that is, you want to interpolate m independent curves, each defined by n points. You have x1 of shape (m, p), that is, you want to evaluate each of the m interpolators at p points.
In your example, you had m = p = 2 and n = 5. Below, we'll use p = 3, m = 2, and n = 500 to interpolate the sin function at 3 different points on 2 different grids, each with 500 points.
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng(238492984583457)

def search_sorted(x, x1):
    # Assumes arrays have same number of dimensions and search
    # is along last axis
    # May not work at boundaries or when elements of x == x1.
    # Might even have off by one errors in other cases.
    a = np.full(x1.shape, 0)
    b = np.full(x1.shape, n-1)

    # bisection for indices of elements in `x` that bound `x1`
    while np.any(b - a > 1):
        c = (a + b) // 2
        x0 = np.take_along_axis(x, c, axis=-1)
        j = x1 > x0
        b = np.where(j, b, c)
        a = np.where(j, c, a)

    # check our work
    assert np.all(np.take_along_axis(x, a, axis=-1) < x1)
    assert np.all(np.take_along_axis(x, a + 1, axis=-1) > x1)
    return a

def interp(x1, x, y):
    # sort x in ascending order for efficient binary search
    j = np.argsort(x, axis=-1)
    x = np.take_along_axis(x, j, axis=-1)
    y = np.take_along_axis(y, j, axis=-1)

    # binary search for adjacent elements of `x` that bound elements of `x1`
    i = search_sorted(x, x1)

    # Interpolation
    xi = np.take_along_axis(x, i, axis=-1)
    xip1 = np.take_along_axis(x, i+1, axis=-1)
    yi = np.take_along_axis(y, i, axis=-1)
    yip1 = np.take_along_axis(y, i+1, axis=-1)
    return yi + (x1 - xi) * (yip1 - yi) / (xip1 - xi)

def f(x):
    return np.sin(x)

n = 500
# Note that arrays are reshaped compared to description
# We could write the function to accept arrays as described
# and automatically reshape them as needed, but that's not the
# point.
x1 = rng.random((3, 2, 1)) * 2 * np.pi
x = rng.random((1, 2, n)) * 2 * np.pi
y = f(x)

np.testing.assert_allclose(interp(x1, x, y), f(x1), rtol=1e-3)

